# Accessing different list elements in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it thread-safe to access (read/write) different elements of the same `ArrayList` from different threads, when no add/remove operations are performed on the list and every thread accesses a fixed set of indexes which do not intersect among threads?
I see no need to use particular precautions here (like locking blocks), but I just wanted to be sure: can something possibly go wrong?

Comment: Is it mandatory to hold all elements in the same collection (perhaps due to post-processing when all threads are finished)? Because if no, you could even use different lists for every thread and combine the lists afterwards if desired.

Comment: well not mandatory, I can always make the threads work on a copy of the values, then update the original list once all the threads are finished by recombining the sublists. However if there are no safety issues I would still prefer the more direct way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. as long as no removes or adds are done the array won't be resized (and thus recreated) and each get(i) call will be safe